# How to change picker modal background in android?

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I'm trying to change picker modal background to another color it's by default White!

I use Picker from "react-native & native-base" but no one works for me!

So is there a way to change it - from native or RN?

Screenshot[image: sc]

Code

```
<View
    style={{
        felx: 1,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#ddd',
        borderColor: '#f05',
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#273137', // it's change the bg but not the modal bg as you see in screenshot
        borderRadius: 4,
     }}>
          <Picker
              style={{
                  height: 40,
                  width: undefined,
                  flex: 1,
                  backgroundColor: '#f00', // not work!

              }}
              mode="dialog" // OR dropdown not change bg color 
              selectedValue={values.gender}
              onValueChange={itemValue =>
              setFieldValue('gender', itemValue)
              }>
                 <Picker.Item
                    color="#ddd"
                    label="gender"
                    value={null}
                    key={0}
                 />
                 <Picker.Item label="male" value={1} key={1} />
                 <Picker.Item label="female" value={2} key={2} />
          </Picker>
</View>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

In the [documentation](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-text-and-item-text-styles-headref) of native base, you have a itemStyle props that you can apply to the Picker component

```
 <Picker
    itemStyle={{
      backgroundColor: "#ddd"            
    }}
  >
```